# Cannot get navigation drawer to function

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to get the drawer to show up at all. Here is my code maybe someone can tell me what is wrong here... The app runs with no errors until I get to the activity with the Drawer then it crashes.

**Here is my code:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

public class FlavorListView extends ActionBarActivity  {

    //shared preference
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu action_setting) {
        //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome,action_setting);

        //drawer
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(FlavorListView.this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
       mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        return true;
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        //return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        //drawer end

        return true;



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_flavor);



        String[] select_flavor_list = {"Kansas City", "Memphis", "Texas", "North Carolina", "South Carolina","Alabama"};


        ListAdapter FlavorListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout_flavor, R.id.flavor_text_view,
                select_flavor_list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(FlavorListAdapter);


        //For list view selection, begin here...
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //String flavorPicked = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                FoodStyleDialog cdd = new FoodStyleDialog(FlavorListView.this);
                cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                cdd.show();
                return true;

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long id) {
                //GlobalClass flavorPref = ((GlobalClass)getApplicationContext());

                String flavorPicked = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (flavorPicked.equals("Kansas City")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FlavorListView.this, KansasCity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    setContentView(R.layout.kansas_city);
                    Toast.makeText(FlavorListView.this, "Looks like " + flavorPicked +
                                    " style be your flavor! You can change your flavor anytime in the settings menu.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
                else if (flavorPicked.equals("Memphis")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FlavorListView.this, KansasCity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    setContentView(R.layout.kansas_city);
                    Toast.makeText(FlavorListView.this, "Looks like " + flavorPicked +
                                    " style be your flavor! You can change your flavor anytime in the settings menu.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });

    }
}
```

I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` and the debugger is saying at `(FlavorListView.java:57)` which is at `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`

IF I comment this line out the app runs but no drawer...

please help. thanks :)

**Drawer Layout xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**FlavorListView Acivity xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".FlavorListView"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Choose Your Flavor"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your xml file select_flavour.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an NPE there, then `mDrawerLayout` must be null. Make sure `drawer_layout` is the right ID to find the drawer in your XML. You need to inflate the Drawer Layout XML file too. You almost have it right (you need to replace `menu_welcome` below with the name of your file):

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome, action_setting);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) action_setting.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
```

Comment: no, I double checked and even changed the id now to be sure, reflection are shown in original message.

Comment: You need to use a `MenuInflater` to inflate the Drawer Layout XML file.

Comment: Same result with `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu action_setting) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome,action_setting);`

Comment: code `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome, action_setting);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) action_setting.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);` doesn't work as `findViewById` shows cannot resolved method

Answer (score 0):

Place below code in your `onCreate` and NOT in

```
onCreateOptionMenu
```

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(FlavorListView.this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
       mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Read the example codes carefully before using it

Comment: it is still throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);`

Comment: @Awatatah please post your logcat of last run